# The Profile data stream has an invalid format when using OpenNLP POSTagger

Tags: opennlp, pos-tagger

I am getting Invalid Format exception. I saw some people suggesting to remove `tags.tagdict` file from `en-pos-maxent.bin` file but I don't know how to do that. Can any one please explain that to me

```
    ava.io.FileInputStream inputStream2 = new java.io.FileInputStream("D://Documents/7090/opennlp-models/en-pos-maxent.bin");
    POSModel pModel = new POSModel(inputStream2);
    POSTaggerME posDetector = new POSTaggerME(pModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`en-pos-maxent.bin` is just a ZIP file, so you can umcompress it and re-compress without that file.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code without any change in `en_pos_maxent.bin`

```
System.setProperty("org.xml.sax.driver", "org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver");
try { 
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = 
    context.getAssets().openFd("en_pos_maxent.bin"); 
    FileInputStream inputStream = fileDescriptor.createInputStream();
    POSModel posModel = new POSModel(inputStream);
    posTaggerME = new POSTaggerME(posModel);
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

rename the `en-pos-maxent.bin` file to `en-pos-maxent.zip`. (If you are using windows you may have to un-hide file extensions. To do this go to control panel -> Apperance and personalization and then click on "folder options." In the view tab look for "hide extensions for known file types" and uncheck that box).

There are 3 files in it and they are:

1. `manifest.properties`
2. `pos.model`
3. `tags.tagdict`

I have seen one post suggesting users delete `tags.tagdict`, but without any reasoning behind it. I have tried this also and it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Hi RobertHana! We are working with this model here and one of our developers here ( @rodrigoteles ) asked to thank you because it realy helped! He does not have enough reputation to do so. +1 for the answer!